# Unit Testing Express Middleware That Verifies Auth Tokens

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, express.js

I am writing an [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) middleware component that'll run on [Node 4](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/), which has limited ES2015 support.

The fundamental purpose of this component is to verify [JSON web tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token), using the [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) module. Here is said component:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = {
  ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const token = req.query.token;
      if (!token) {
        return reject({
          status: 401
        });
      } else {
        jwt
          .verify(token, "secret", function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
              return reject({
                status: 401
              });
            } else {
              req.user = decoded;
              resolve();
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I also wrote some unit tests, using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/):

```
const chai = require("chai");
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
const httpMocks = require("node-mocks-http");

const expect = chai.expect;

suite("ensureAuthenticated", function() {

  test("should return 401 when token is \"undefined\"", function() {
    const sut = require("../../middleware");
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest();

    return sut
      .ensureAuthenticated(req)
      .catch(function(outcome) {
        expect(outcome.status).to.equal(401);
      });
  });

  test("should return 401 when token is invalid", function() {
    const jsonwebtoken = { };
    jsonwebtoken.verify = function(token, secret, cb) {
      cb({});
    };
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
      query: {
        token: "bar"
      }
    });
    const sut = proxyquire("../../middleware", {
      jsonwebtoken: jsonwebtoken
    });

    return sut
      .ensureAuthenticated(req)
      .catch(function(outcome) {
        expect(outcome.status).to.equal(401);
      });
  });

  test("should add decoded data to req object when token is valid", function() {
    const decoded = {
      username: "dummy username"
    };
    const jsonwebtoken = { };
    jsonwebtoken.verify = function(token, secret, cb) {
      cb(undefined, decoded);
    };
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
      query: {
        token: "dummy token"
      }
    });
    const sut = proxyquire("../../middleware", {
      jsonwebtoken: jsonwebtoken
    });

    return sut
      .ensureAuthenticated(req)
      .then(function() {
        expect(req.user).to.equal(decoded);
      });
  });
});
```

As you can see, the component returns a `Promise`, which makes it unit-testable. I got the idea from [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwNMUVzo3vs).

I would please like to hear any thoughts you have about the quality of my tests. I am also interested in any general criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only looked at the tests briefly, but they look good and I like your approach

The following changes will help the readability of your main code:

- Prefer early returning guard clauses over if/else.  It's easier to follow, uses less code, and avoids a level of indentation.
- Name concepts clearly and move them to helper functions, so that your main body expresses its intent better: see `notAuthorized()`
- Arguably a personal preference, but consider it: For short, one-line if statements, don't use brackets and put them on a single line.

Rewrite (note this hasn't been tested, so it's possible there are trivial errors):

```
module.exports = {
  ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      // Use guard clause rather if / else
      const token = req.query.token;
      if (!token) return notAuthorized();

      jwt.verify(token, "secret", function(err, decoded) {

        if (err) return notAuthorized();
        req.user = decoded;
        resolve();
      });

    });
    function notAuthorized() { return reject({ status: 401}) }
  }
};
```

Comment: _"one-line if statements, don't use brackets and put them on a single line"_ Yeah, my linter will complain if I do that. Thanks for the answer, though! Accepted.